# Density function involving floor function

Tags: probability, distributions

Let $Z$ have a uniform distribution on $[−0.5, 0.5]$. Let $X$ be a continuous random variable
which is independent of $Z$. Let$$Y = ⌊X + Z⌋ − Z.$$
I would like to ask how to compute the marginal density function and joint density function of $Y$ and $X-Y$. I have zero idea on how to deal with the floor function. I only knew that $$⌊x+ n⌋=⌊x⌋+n$$
when n is an integer. However $Z$ is in the range $[−0.5, 0.5]$.

Comment: Consider $Y=y$. Then there exists a single $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $|y-n|<.5$. Hence $y$ determines both the realisation of $Z$ and of $\lfloor X+Z \rfloor$.